# My CMD Prompt won't stay open

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Haven't reinstalled Windows for well over a year, so I know it's overdue, and that would obviously fix this, but hoping to figure it out first.

If I open my CMD it flashes up on the screen and then disappears.  Doesn't matter how I open it, shortcut, typing etc, it does this.  Doesn't log anything that I can find.  It's been doing this for quite a while now, at least 6 months.

Now if I type a ping -t command for instance, it will stay up while it's doing it, so I don't think it's the app itself.  Tried it in safe mode and it does the exact same thing.  Windows updates are up to date - now, I had had them off, but relented but it doesn't matter.

I thought about replacing CMD.exe with another copy but couldn't find it in the Windows ISO I had downloaded.  I assume it's buried in a CAB file..

Have done the SFC /scannow in both regular and safe mode, as well as in startup mode, and it says it finds something wrong, but as usual can't do anything about it.

TIA

Comment: Reverse the steps @John suggested in his answer: Reboot Windows, then run the following in an Admin terminal: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` > Reboot.  > Run the following in an Admin terminal: `sfc /scannow` > Reboot. If that does not fix your issue, you can either research on different forums ([TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home), [Windows 10 forum](https://www.tenforums.com/), etc.) or perform a repair install (run Windows setup while booted to Windows and select "upgrade"), as the issue could be a myriad of things.

Answer (score 1):

You ran SFC.

Now open `cmd.exe` with Run as Administrator, see if it stays open and run

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Another way is to open the Search bar (left side) type in the command (all of it), do not press enter, select (from the search dialogue window) Run as Administrator.

You can also open Task Manager, select File, Run new Task, enter the DISM string above, check the box Run with Administrative privileges and see if that runs

See if DISM repairs the issue

Comment: You have the steps in the wrong order =]  `dism /online /cleanup-image /restoreheath` must be ran before `sfc /scannow` due to what each does.  The DISM command verifies the backup copies of all Windows system files contained within `C:\Windows\WinSxS` matches the hashes of known good copies from Windows Update, and if a mis-matched hash [corruption] is found, replaces the backup in WinSxS with the known good copy.  SFC then verifies all system files, excl. WinSxS, matches the hashes of the known good backup copies contained within WinSxS, and if corruption is found, replaces the system file.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to answer this when I figured it out.  I hadn't seen the answer of JW0914, which may or  may not have solved it.  Turned out to be malware.  Windows Defender was up to date, but didn't see it, but a MWB scan found it.  Don't remember what is was.